# This issue causes multiple queries instead of one and negatively affects site performance

Tags: magento2

i am getting category by below code

```
  public function  get_categories($categories) 
{ //This is the recursive function created and here we pass the a collection of categories.
  //$array is a variable to store all the category detail .
    $array = array();
    foreach($categories as $category) {

            $cat = $this->getCategoryModel()->load($category->getId());
            $array[$category->getLevel()][$cat->getId()]= array('id' => $cat->getId(), 'level' => $cat->getLevel(), 'name' => $cat->getName(), 'url' => $cat->getUrl(), 'display_mode' => $cat->getDisplayMode(), 'image' => $cat->getImageUrl('wizard_icon'), 'description' => $cat->getWizardQuestion(), 'categories' => [] ); //In this line we get an a link for the product and product count of that category
            if($category->hasChildren()) {  //if category has children or not. If yes then it proceed in inside loop.
                 $children = $category->getChildrenCategories(); // $children get a list of all subcategories
                $array[$category->getLevel()][$cat->getId()]['categories']=  $this->get_categories($children); //recursive call the get_categories function again.
                }

        }
    return  $array;
}
```

but the issue is

```
$this->get_categories($children);
```

This issue causes multiple queries instead of one and negatively affects site performance.

Comment: You are using `load` inside a foreach loop which is not a good approach. It will execute query to load the category each time the loop will iterate. You should use collection filter to fetch all categories at once and then process that collection in your loop.

Comment: so any code you can give me

Comment: I am not sure why you are loading the category in loop. Can't you directly use your `$categories` variable to get category data?

Comment: i am using filter